# When looking to buy a router for home use what are the specs/features that I should be aware of?

Tags: networking, router

I've looked into buying a router, rather than renting from my ISP, multiple times but have no idea what the differences are between a bottom of the line router or a top of the line router.

I would guess the wireless signal strength would be one of the main things but how can I tell by looking at the box what the differences are even for this?  I would be using this for general home use as well as gaming.

Comment: I've closed this question because it's more of a general advice-type question, which [are no longer in scope](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want‌​-general-advice-questions/345#345).

Answer (score 11):

**Security**

- Can the [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) be configured such that future configuration changes can only be made from the [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) and not from the [WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network)?
- Is the router protected from [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)/[XSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks which could let websites visited by computers on your LAN get control over the router?
- Does the vendor provide [firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) [security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security) updates, and are they easy to install? Is it also easy to downgrade to a previous firmware version?

**IPv4 NAT**

I guess more than 99% of users currently need [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) for [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) traffic, you can expect pretty much all routers to support this, but the quality varies.

- How many connection tracking entries can the router handle?
- What happens when the limit is exceeded?
- Can the router be configured to [forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) ports from WAN to LAN?
- Can the router be configured to forward [protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) without port numbers from WAN to LAN?
- Can the [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server on the router be configured with both static and dynamic assignments?
- Can the DHCP server on the router 
  be configured to be hand out [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) server addresses of your own choice?

**IPv6**

Current [trends](https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html) indicate that the majority of users will be using [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) three years from now. If you intend to use the router for more than three years, you are likely going to need IPv6.

- Does the router support it at all?
- Can the router be configured over IPv6? (This is not critical, but it can be very convenient).
- Can the router be configured with static IPv6 on the WAN?
- Can the router be configured to act as DHCPv6 client on the WAN?
- Can the DHCPv6 client request a [prefix delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_delegation) from the [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider)?
- Can the router forward packets in [hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Example_applications)? (If not, the [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) may become a bottleneck)

**Wireless**

- Can it be configured with dual [SSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Service_set_identification_.28SSID.29)?
- Can it be configured with a guest [segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segment) which cannot communicate with wired LAN ports?
- Can it measure ambient [noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_(radio)) level across the [frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) band and automatically choose the channel with least noise?

Keep in mind that if reliably low [latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(engineering)) and low packet loss is needed, [WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) will never beat a wired connection.

Answer (score 5):

Kasperd's answer is good, but there are some other critical things to look for:

**Reliability**
Many routers have software that is so poor that it crashes, sometimes as often as every few days. Some routers are made poorly and the hardware fails after a few months or a year.

**Compatibility**
Some routers have compatibility issues with some devices.

Either of these can make your nice new router useless.